# Can the GPIO interfere with the PiCamera and cause an error?

Tags: gpio, python

I have a Pi NoIR camera setup to take a still image every 60 seconds with a Python3 script. This is set to run for about 12 hours from 7pm to 7am.
This setup worked as intended without any problems. I then added a IR LED flash that is controlled by GPIO pin 17(BCM). Originally this just turned on and off. However, since changing the code to run the pin at 50% PWM I get the following error after a few hours of execution:

```
picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Timed out waiting for capture to end
```

I've tried my original script again and it runs without error. The error only seems to occur when I use PWM.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import picamera
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def capture_frame(_still):
#Record time and date
strNow = dtCurrent.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
dbdate = dtCurrent.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
dbtime = dtCurrent.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

#Configure flash pin
flash = GPIO.PWM(17,120)

with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
    cam.resolution = (640, 480)
    cam.annotate_text = strNow
    #GPIO.output(17, 1)
    flash.start(50)
    time.sleep(1)
    cam.capture('/home/pi/monitor/images/{0:4d}.jpg' . format(still), resize=(480, 360))
    cam.close()
    #GPIO.output(17, 0)
    flash.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a bug in RPi.GPIO brought to light because of the way you are using the PWM functions.  Check to see if it's a known issue at http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/ and perhaps raise an issue.

Rather than `flash.start(50)` and `flash.stop()`
try using `flash.ChangeDutyCycle(50.0)` and `flash.ChangeDutyCycle(0.0)`

Comment: [GPIO ticket #94](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/94/)
This explains everything very nicley. My error occured at around 360 to 380 images taken. I shall use flash.ChangeDutyCycle instead.